# fading in hidden text using jquery on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to fade in the `.example` element which is hidden using:

```
.example {

    display: none;

 }
```

the javascript:

```
$('.clickme').click( function() {
   .....
   ....

 $el.html(html).children().hide().each(function(i, e){
    if($(this).hasClass('special')){
      $(this).delay(i*600).show(0);
      animateDiv(e.id);
    }
    else{
        $(this).delay(i*600).fadeIn(900); // the problem is here its not fading in
    }
```

working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/6czap/19/

i cnt seem to find out what the problem is, i have tried this without the click event, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .show() after you alter the contents of .example div.

```
$el.html(html).show()...
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6czap/24/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `example` class from the div or it will never show the contents. See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6czap/25/).

```
$el.removeClass("example").html(html).children().hide().each(...)
```